# Mysql Select and Insert into another table with Php foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a created a new table (colours) which has id and hex as columns, all existing ids are kept in the pics table along with the path of the picture, which will go into the new colours table with the many hex values. I am using a class to extract the prominent colours from the picture as array of hex values.

This is the code so far:

```
$data = $conn->query('SELECT id,pic_path FROM pics WHERE pic_id = 1231');
while($row = $data->fetch()) {
    $image = new ColorsOfImage('images/'.$data['pic_path']);
    $colors = $image->getProminentColors();

    foreach($colors as $key => $val)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO colours (pic_id,colour) VALUES (:pic_id,:colour)";
        $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array(':pic_id'=>$data['pic_id'],':colour'=>$val));
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array
```

This is how it should look like this once it's populated:

[image: sample fields]

Comment: @Dagon please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done with one single query, no php, no loop required

```
INSERT INTO colours (pic_id,colour)
SELECT id,pic_path FROM pics
WHERE pic_id = 1231
```

full details: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Comment: Oh I see, I only used pic_id to test, really I would use something like WHERE pic_id >1231, would that work?

Comment: i only know one way to find out

Answer (score 2):

You used `$data['pic_id']` when what you wanted was `$row['pic_id']`.

Comment: Wow! That was a daft oversight! Thanks